# Find strings in list using wildcard

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am looking for some file names in a list using a wildcard.

```
from datetime import date
dt = str("RT" + date.today().strftime('%d%m'))
print dt # RT0701
```

Basically I need to find this pattern `dt + "*.txt"` :

```
RT0701*.txt
```

In this list:

```
l = ['RT07010534.txt', 'RT07010533.txt', 'RT02010534.txt']
```

How can i do that with a for loop?

Comment: Are they in a directory initially?If so use `glob.glob("path/to/{}*.txt".format(l,dt)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I just need to work with strings, not files. thanks

Comment: Also see [**`fnmatch`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`fnmatch.filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) for this:

```
import fnmatch
l = ['RT07010534.txt', 'RT07010533.txt', 'RT02010534.txt']
pattern = 'RT0701*.txt'
matching = fnmatch.filter(l, pattern)
print(matching)
```

Outputs:

```
['RT07010534.txt', 'RT07010533.txt']
```

Answer (score 2):

sth like this (without using regexes, which is another option)

```
matches = []
for file in list:
    if file.startswith(dt) and '.txt' == file[-4:]: matches.append(file)

print (matches)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex like so:

```
import re
pat = re.compile('%s.*\.txt' % dt)
for can in l:
    if(pat.search(can)):
        print can
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have to opitons: 

for eachLine in pingFile:
    # start_with_no = (i for i in mylist if i.startswith("no"))
    numberOfLines += 1
    eachLineSplit = eachLine.split(" ")
    for x in range(0,len(eachLineSplit)):
        if "ttl" in eachLineSplit[x]:
            print(x)


and 

eachLineSplit = ['x.x.x.x', 'time=12.222', 'test' 'test2']
time_find = [i for i, item in enumerate(eachLineSplit) if item.startswith('time=')]
print(time_find)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you have "two" options??

Answer (score 0):

Same way as Eric Renouf using Regex, but a little bit shorter and simpler (i.e., no regex language):

```
lst = ['RT07010534.txt', 'RT07010533.txt', 'RT02010534.txt']
import re 
matchedLst=[m for m in lst if re.search('RT0701', m)]
print(matchedLst)
```

Results:

```
['RT07010534.txt', 'RT07010533.txt']
```